# If we have to create multiple pages using a viewpager in android, then do we have to create multiple fragments? Is there any other alternative?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I'm creating an android quiz application in which I'll be using a viewpager. I've gone through some tutorials in which for each new page a new class is created for fragment/tabs. Now if I want to have total 15 pages, then will I have to create that much classes? Isn't there any other alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Each page in the `ViewPager` will be a different *instance* of a `Fragment`, but there's no requirement that each page be a different `class` of `Fragment`.

In an excessively simple application, you could imagine that each page in the `ViewPager` would just show a different number. You could achieve this by creating a `OneFragment` class to show "1", a `TwoFragment` class to show "2", and so on. Or, you could create a single `NumberFragment` class and use fifteen different instances to show fifteen different numbers:

```
public class NumberFragment extends Fragment {

    public static NumberFragment newInstance(int number) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("number", number);

        NumberFragment fragment = new NumberFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.number_fragment, container, false);

        int number = getArguments().getInt("number");
        String numberText = String.valueOf(number);

        TextView numberView = root.findViewById(R.id.numberView);
        numberView.setText(numberText);

        return root;
    }
}
```

With this in place, your `FragmentPagerAdapter` is incredibly simple:

```
public class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return NumberFragment.newInstance(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 15;
    }
}
```

This same concept applies even in more complex applications. As long as each page of the `ViewPager` has the same structure to its data, you can just create a new instance of a single `Fragment` class by passing the necessary configuration to `newInstance()`.

You can also mix-and-match this technique with the one where you create a new `Fragment` subclass for each page. Maybe you want your first and your last pages to be unique, but the thirteen middle pages are all basically the same.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Well, I'm a beginner in android, so how will this work in my case? On each page I have to display a new question with corresponding radio buttons.I'm really confused where to store the data and display it accordingly on the pages.

Comment: That depends on how the questions are represented in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `Fragment` for each different page you want to show in the `ViewPager`. Then you could select each `Fragment` by the position in the `FragmentPagerAdapter`.